Error creating droplet: json: cannot unmarshal number 2296635920 into Go struct field LinkAction.links.actions.id of type int
I'm learning Terraform so I decided that I want to create a droplet where I deploy a simple express app just to test how it creates the droplet.
Well, I'm getting the following error
Error creating droplet: json: cannot unmarshal number 2296635920 into Go struct field LinkAction.links.actions.id of type int
I searched for anything with a similar error and I couldn't find anything.
I turned on TF_LOG=DEBUG and got the following
"links": {
  "actions": [
   {
    "id": 2296635920,
    "rel": "create",
    "href": "https://api.digitalocean.com/v2/actions/2296635920"
   }
  ]
 }

This "actions" attriubte's id is not parsed correctly by the provider since it exceeds the 32-bit int limit, but further than that I'm lost.
Here is my main.tf file as well:
terraform {
  required_providers {
    digitalocean = {
      source  = "digitalocean/digitalocean"
      version = "2.41.0"
    }
  }
}

variable "digitalocean_token" {
  description = "DigitalOcean API token"
  type        = string
}

provider "digitalocean" {
  token = var.digitalocean_token
}

resource "digitalocean_ssh_key" "default" {
  name       = "ssh-key"
  public_key = file("~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub")
}

resource "digitalocean_droplet" "web" {
  name  = "express-app"
  size  = "s-1vcpu-1gb"
  image = "ubuntu-24-04-x64"
  region = "ams3"

  ssh_keys = [ digitalocean_ssh_key.default.fingerprint ]

  connection {
    type        = "ssh"
    host        = self.ipv4_address
    user        = "root"
    private_key = file("~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub")
  }

  provisioner "remote-exec" {
    inline = [
      "apt-get update",
      "apt-get install -y nodejs npm",
      "npm install -g pm2",
      "mkdir /app",
      "echo 'Deploying application...'",
      "cp -r /tmp/my-express-app/* /app/",
      "cd /app && npm install",
      "pm2 start app.js --name my-express-app",
      "pm2 startup",
      "pm2 save"
    ]
  }

}


Is the problem coming from the provider or am I doing anything wrong?

Not really sure, but can you try with user_data instead of using the remote-exec provisioner?

I tried using user_data and it's the same error.
